# Bars are not appearing in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using a stacked bar in highcharts. i am not able to see the bars in my code. can any one help me..?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cricket Stars</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-playerstats></app-playerstats>
</body>
</html>
```

playerstats.html

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

playerstats.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
declare var Highcharts: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-player-stats',
  templateUrl: './player-stats.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-stats.component.css']
})

export class PlayerStatsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //bating charts
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        fontFamily: 'arial',
        color: "#ffffff"
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
      tooltip: { enabled: false },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
        // enabled: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['MAT', 'RUNS', 'SR', 'AVG', 'HS', 'NO'],
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        lineWidth: 2,
        labels: {
          style: {
             color: '#ffffff',
             font: '11px sans-serif',
             fontWeight:'bold'
          }
       }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        lineWidth: 2,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: [],
        title: {
          // text: 'Total fruit consumption'
          enabled: false
        },
      },
      legend: {
        reversed: true,
        symbolRadius: 0,
        align: "center",
        // contentAlign:"left"
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          // pointPadding: 10,
          // groupPadding: 10,
        },
        bar: {
          pointWidth: 38,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Player stats',
        data: [1000, 786, 900, 889, 787, 956],
        color: 'red'

      }, {
        name: 'Topper Stats',
        data: [450, 564, 400, 100, 450, 77],
        color:'green'
      }]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried reproducing your issue, but it is working for me. See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddhqrf) StackBlitz.

Comment: Check this example with `highcharts-angular` wrapper used: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-wp0rr. Also, it's working perfectly fine.